# Starting WebView Activity causes "Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

When I try to open an Activity (with `WebView` inside) like this:

```
private val importUserConnection = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ 
        activityResult -> println(activityResult)
}

private val openWebLogin(){
    val loginIntent = Intent(this, FAWebLoginActivity::class.java)
    loginIntent.putExtra("FormUrl", response.getString("url"))
    loginIntent.putExtra("FormId", response.getString("id"))
    importUserConnection.launch(login)
}
```

FAWebLoginActivity doesn't open (no crash) and I'm getting following exception:

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Se2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor;
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5199)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5393)
  at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:660)
  at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
  at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
  at void com.yyyyy.xxxxxxxxxxx.activities.FAWebLoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FAWebLoginActivity.kt:24)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7327)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7318)
  at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3094)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3257)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1948)
  at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
  at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
  at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.PacProcessor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
  at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5199)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5393)
  at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:660)
  at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
  at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
  at void com.yyyyy.xxxxxxxxxxx.activities.FAWebLoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FAWebLoginActivity.kt:24)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7327)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7318)
  at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3094)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3257)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1948)
  at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
  at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
  at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Se2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor;
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5199)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5393)
  at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:660)
  at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
  at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
  at void com.yyyyy.xxxxxxxxxxx.activities.FAWebLoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FAWebLoginActivity.kt:24)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7327)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7318)
  at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3094)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3257)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1948)
  at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
  at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
  at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.PacProcessor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-gB7COKcevzhR1AjBnPvR-g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
  at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5199)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5393)
  at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:660)
  at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
  at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
  at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
  at void com.yyyyy.xxxxxxxxxxx.activities.FAWebLoginActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FAWebLoginActivity.kt:24)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7327)
  at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7318)
  at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3094)
  at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3257)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1948)
  at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
  at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:214)
  at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
  at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<Se2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/PacProcessor;
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:176)
  at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:459)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:251)
  at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2681)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2676)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2741)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:5199)
  at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5393)
  at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:660)
  at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:659)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:604)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:587)
  at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:574)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
  at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
  at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
  at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)

**...**
```

Comment: I'm not sure but my team and I think that `mWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true` solved the problem.

Comment: Don't take GeckoView unless you want to build your own browser. Because with GeckoView my app became 5 times bigger.